# mime type not found for file upload in Symfony functional test

Tags: php, upload, symfony1, functional-testing

When I run my functional tests through Symfony, the uploaded file is not being supplied with a mime type.

My test case shows:

```
$browser->info('1 - Test Upload Form')->
  get('/formpage')->
  setField('myform[file]', sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/example.doc')->
  click('input[type=submit]')->
  end
;
```

And is executed on the command line like so:

```
./symfony test:functional frontend upload
```

The output given is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => example.doc
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => /.../web/uploads/example.doc
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 15360
)
```

Why is no mime type provided?  Is there a way to put the mime type in?

Answer (score 1):

Info

if u know the error. Then try to clear it first before testing. Use like this..

```
$filename . $extension ;
$extension  =  $file -> getExtension ( $file -> getOriginalExtension ( ) ) ;
```